# no exports were found that match the constraint:ContractName

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, cordova

I am using MS Visual Studio Professional 2012, Version: 11.0.51106.01. Since past few days realized that i am no more able to create a new project with template JavaScript. I was able to do this before. I am guessing this might have happened due to some system update.

Here is the error log when i try to create a new project:

no exports were found that match the constraint:ContractName
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextDocumentFactoryService
RequiredTypeIdentity
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextDocumentFactoryService

Please help me resolve this issue at the earliest as i have not been able to find much online.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the link :

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2013/09/29/visual-studio-2012-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name/

This worked for me.

> Remove ComponentModelCache folder content.
>   %AppData%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache

Comment: This worked for me (in Visual Studio 2013)

Comment: That worked for me (VS2012). Save me time!