# No exports where found that match the constraint: Contractname. When creating an universal app new project

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app

I am running Visual Studio 2013 update 4 and Visual Studio 2015 RC

I get this message in 2013:
[image]
[image]
[image]
I have read both [no exports were found that match the constraint:ContractName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374506/no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraintcontractname)
and [Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name)

I have several folders in

> C:\Users\JP\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio

10, 11, 12, 14

11 has only a designer folder, so I can skip that one. 12 had a `ComponentModelCache` folder which I renamed to `ComponentModelCache-old`
same for 14. (I also renamed that componentmodelcache folder)

But the message stays. The 2015 gives me "Download Windows Universal Tools" which is only available for windows 10 and I am running 8.1 so that is no option. It worked before... It seems related to this question:
[Cannot load shared 'project' in Windows Universal app after upgrading to Azure SDK 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966312/cannot-load-shared-project-in-windows-universal-app-after-upgrading-to-azure-s)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8123821-dcb1-477f-a746-f6f016a724ea/cannot-load-shared-project-in-windows-universal-app-after-upgrading-to-azure-sdk-26?forum=azuremobile&prof=required#de621720-3afc-458c-ba85-f691be9e74c1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested on msdn: Uninstall Azure SDK for VS 2.6